# Read only a required function in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to guess the type of a variable based on its usage in a function. For this, I decided to use Regex in which I will have a list of expressions for every type. Like, for an integer, a few possible expressions could be,

```
'''
pattern = [r"[a-z]\s\+", r"[a-z]\s\-", r"[a-z]\s\*", r"[a-z]\s\/", r"[a-z]\s\=\s[0-9]", r"[a-z]\s\=\=\s[0-9]*"]
'''
```

I want to search for these patterns for every variable in a function and decide the type.
But, To do this, I need to consider only the function,i.e, I need to read the lines of only the required function from a big python file. 
Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: For both your questions: you may want to check [Python's own Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

Comment: You're essentially trying to reproduce how the Python parser interprets literals, that's going to be LOTS of different patterns and very difficult to be complete. There are many cases, like multi-line expressions, escape characters, etc. Use the AST library as suggested.